# No get query sting data in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, get, query-string

I'm trying to get query string parameters tho, it's blank.
This is URL.

`https://master.deeiswmgeowge.amplifyapp.com/?site=gfg&subject=react`

Then, `this.props` is empty.

The below is the source.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
// Importing Module 
import queryString from 'query-string'
  
class App extends Component { 
  
  state = { 
    site: 'unknown', 
    subject: 'i dont know'
  } 
  
  handleQueryString = () => { 
    // Parsing the query string  
    // Using parse method 
    console.log(`this.props`, this.props)
    let queries = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search) 
    console.log(queries) 
    this.setState(queries) 
  } 
  
  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div style={{ margin: 200 }}> 
          
        <p> WebSite: {this.state.site} </p> 
          
                  
        <p> Subject: {this.state.subject} </p> 
  
        <button 
          onClick={this.handleQueryString} 
          className='btn btn-primary'> 
          click me 
        </button> 
      </div> 
    ); 
  } 
} 
  
export default App;
```

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "query-string": "^6.14.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

This is the error image.

[image]

Comment: You don't show what props are being passed into your `App` component. What props are getting passed in?

Comment: From the syntax you're using to access the query parameters, I am assuming you're using `react-router` but I can't see that added as a dependency in your `package.json`.

Comment: There is no `location` in your `props`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using react router , thus no location parameter in props :

so you have two solution ,

- 1 whether  adding [`react-router-dom`](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) and wrap your app with router , ( or using with router hook  like `export default withRouter(App)`)
- 2 or access directly `window.location.search` and get params with [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#browser_compatibility)

by example :

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const site = urlParams.get('site');
const subject = urlParams.get('subject');
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to pass the props like

```
onClick={()=>  this.handleQueryString(this.props)}
```

and received like

```
handleQueryString(arg) {
....
}
```